# Return a matching result in the view across three models in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm inheriting a codebase for a Rails app that uses a blog engine -- and I am not making sense of how the models interact.

What I want to do is show the author who is associated with a specific article.

There is a table for articles called `LinesArticle`. An example entry:

```
<LinesArticle id: 2, title: "Example Article", sub_title: "Example Title", 
content: "Example Content", published: true, published_at: "2017-08-22 00:00:00", 
created_at: "2017-08-23 06:15:33", updated_at: "2017-08-23 06:15:36", slug: "whatever", 
featured: false, document: nil, short_hero_image: "", teaser: "">
```

Next, there is a table for Authors called `LinesAuthor`. An example entry that should be associated:

```
#<LinesAuthor id: 1, name: "John Doe", email: "jd@examplesitedotcom", created_at: "2017-08-19 07:46:04", updated_at: "2017-08-19 07:46:04">
```

So if I compare these two tables, there isn't a connection between the data that would make sense for the models. So then I found `LinesAuthorable` that I think connects them. An entry:

```
<LinesAuthorable id: 2, author_id: 1, article_id: 2, 
created_at: "2017-08-23 06:15:33", updated_at: "2017-08-23 06:15:33">
```

So my thinking is, if my controller calls an article like `@articles = LinesArticle.last` and I want to show the author who wrote that article by matching `article_id` to the matching result in `LinesAuthorable` and then query `LinesAuthor` for the matching `author_id`.

Reading through the documentation, I have now created models where an Article model `belongs_to :lines_authorable` and Author `has_many :Lines_Authorable`. If that is the right approach, how would you call that in the view to actually show the Author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinesAuthorable` table is acting as a through table, you can use a has_many through relationship to connect the data, something like:

```
class LinesArticle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines_authorables, foreign_key: :article_id
  has_many :lines_authors, through: :lines_authorables
end

class LinesAuthor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines_authorables, foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :lines_articles, through: :lines_authorables
end

class LinesAuthorable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :line_article, foreign_key: :article_id
  belongs_to :line_author, foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

You can then access an article's authors, and likewise an author's articles directly through the relationship:

```
@article = LinesArticle.first
@article.lines_authors #=> #<LinesAuthor::ActiveRecord_Relation...>

@author = LinesAuthor.first
@author.lines_articles #=> #<LinesArticle::ActiveRecord_Relation...>
```